# does it drop temp table (created in transaction) if rollback transaction in sql server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the transaction, I created some temp tables and inserted some data. if everything goes ok, the temp tables will be dropped and then the transaction will be committed. if there is exception, the connection will be close.

My question is: Do I have to rollback the transaction before close the connection? or, as long as the connection is closed, it is ok?

If I rollback, I assume the temp tables created in transaction will be dropped (rollback) too, correct?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temp table will be dropped when it's out of scope.

However losing a connection while having a transaction open creates an orphaned transaction, and any locks it holds will remain.

Using SET XACT_ABORT should rollback any transaction as soon as a run-time error is encountered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx

Comment: To add some clarity here, if you are catching in C# and closing the connection, you are closing it outside of an exception and will not cause an orphan.  If your procedure causes an exception, you have a possible orphan.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use a TRY CAtCH block and a specific rollback so that I also can capture the error and or the data causing the error in a logging table after the rollback. If you are doing things complex enough to need an explicit transaction, you porbaly want the logging to be able to troubleshoot problems later on when they occur.

Answer (score 2):

The temp table will drop as soon as it is out of scope.  Closing the connection puts it out of scope regardless of whether or not it rolls back.